# CSS Pseudo Class Selectors

Tags: css, css-transitions, pseudo-class

How would you / or is it possible to create an animation in css3 after the object in question has lost focus?

Example:
You Hover over a picture and a box appears above the picture slides into view like-so:

```
.product_title {
    border:5px solid black; 
    width:0px; 
    height:0px; 
    background-color:#deddcd; 
    /* margin:-130px 0 0 200px; */
    position:relative;
    z-index: 10;
    border-radius: 10px;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
.product_wrap:hover .product_title {
    width:154px; 
    height:164px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -ms-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    overflow: visible;
    position: absolute;
```

Now what I want to do is "after" I move the mouse from the current object onto the next this activates the object I have just "lost focus" with to do transition-duration as well. That way the box that appeared smoothly in 0.8s will disappear smoothly in 0.8s instead of instantaneously.

Is it possible to do this with CSS3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
-moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
-ms-transition-duration: 0.8s;
```

to .product_title as well.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/pcJQ5/

Comment: was a little bit more complex than that - as I have several divs nested between the product_wrap and product_title. Got it working with a little bit of tinkering. The "position" of the box moved below the image div within the product_wrapper. Since product_title was set as relative when not being hovered over. It would push it below the image and with overflow: hidden you could not see it the animation effect. I had to set it to absolute and opacity to 0 and then 0.9 for opacity while being hovered - to do the trick. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't track if you have lost focus in css3, you will have to achieve this in combination with javascript.